# How to run commands depending on players scoreboard?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I teleport players based on their score on the scoreboard? For example, only if there scoreboard score is 1.

Comment: I cannot understand your question, can you clarify / rewrite it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
/tp @p[score_*Score*_min=1] x y z
```

Comment: although this answer may be corrected, it's best to explain *why* it's correct. What are the parts of this command and how would the asker (or other people with similar problems) use it?

Comment: well, good point.  I actually have no idea why I posted this answer, as the person above me basically stated the same thing lol.

Answer (score 8):

In the selector arguments, use `score_SCORENAME=` and `score_SCORENAME_min=`. For example, to teleport a player with at least 1 of a "Kills" objective:

```
/tp @a[score_Kills_min=1] 0 70 0
```

Answer (score -2):

```
/execute @a[score_(YOUR SCOREBOARD NAME)_min=(MINIMUM SCOREBOARD VALUE)] ~ ~ ~ /(COMMAND TO EXECUTE ON SELECTED PLAYER)
```

I used

```
/execute @a[score_rightClick_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /kill @p
```

to detect when someone used a carrot on a stick by setting up a scoreboard called `rightClick`.

Comment: `/execute` is unnecessary here and just causes more work for the server to be done. You should only be using it if the sender or origin needs to be changed, which is not the case here. In fact, this setup may end up killing every player online. Only the `@a` selector can target dead players, so if a player dies with the relevant score they will first kill themselves, and then since `@p` cannot target themselves anymore, they'll kill the nearest-living player to them in the next tick, and so on until all players are dead.