# How do I teleport a player that has two specific scores in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit

I am making a bukkit minecraft server and I want to know how to make a player that has a score of 1 on one scoreboard objective, and 3 on another.

Something like this right?

```
/tp @a[score_scoreboard=1,score_anotherscoreboard=3] (coords)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your Bukkit plugins don't interfere with vanilla commands (and if one *does*, go and hit the plugin dev with oak wood planks), your problem is most likely a misunderstanding of the target selector arguments.

There are two target selector arguments for every scoreboard objective: `score_NAME=X` and `score_NAME_min=X`, where `NAME` is the name of the objective, and `X` is an integer number. The first one checks for the *maximum*, the second for the *minimum* score needed to be a valid target. To target someone with an `OBJ1` of at *exactly* 4, you have to use *both*.

```
@a[score_OBJ1_min=4,score_OBJ1=4]
```

This can be expanded almost infinitely with more objectives, for example

```
@a[score_OBJ1_min=4,score_OBJ1=4,score_OBJ2_min=2,score_OBJ2=2,score_OBJ3_min=66,score_OBJ3=99]
```

would target any player with an `OBJ1` score of 4, `OBJ2` score of 2, and `OBJ3` score between 66 and 99 (inclusive).

In your teleport example, you'd use

```
/tp @a[score_scoreboard=1,score_scoreboard_min=1,score_anotherscoreboard=3,score_anotherscoreboard_min=3] (coords)
```

Comment: You may have to do /minecraft:tp... for the command, some versions of bucket change the default tp mechanics, so you have the add minecraft: to tell bucket to use the default minecraft command

Answer (score 1):

To those looking at this and using 1.13+, here's the new format (using MrLemon's example):

`/tp @a[scores={scoreboard=1,anotherscoreboard=3}] X Y Z`

You may also run the command as the player directly:

`/execute as @a[scores={scoreboard=1,anotherscoreboard=3}] at @s run tp @s X Y Z`

TIP: Adding ellipses (..) you can get a range of values:

- `scoreboard=..2` = any value less than or equal to 2 (including negative values)
- `scoreboard=0..2` = any value greater than or euqual to 0 and less than or equal to 2
- `scoreboard=2..` = any value greater than or equal to 2

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, but it has little to do with bukkit servers since /tp and scoreboards are available in vanilla and singleplayer

Answer (score 0):

The command you listed above is an accurate command. There may be something wrong with your computer, or you typed in something wrong. Remember to hook the command block up to a repeating circuit. A possible solution for you is the command

```
/testfor @a[score_scoreboard=1,score_anotherscoreboard=3]
```

placed in a command block connected to a repeating circuit, and a redstone comparator coming out of it, and going to a command block with the command `/tp @p x y z`, but sadly, that would only work if you had one person on the server, or just on the person nearest to the command block. If you need it to work with multiple people in random locations, then you can try this slightly different command:

```
/tp @p[score_Scorename_min=1,score_Scorename2_min=1] x y z
```

where 1 is the minimum number that their score can be.

Proof That the `/tp` command actually works:

- [Minecraft Forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/350979-question-is-it-possible-to-teleport-players-based)
- [Previously Asked Araque Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/199246/how-to-run-commands-depending-on-players-scoreboard)

Comment: I guess it's just bukkit that's doing it... I don't think player selectors like @p, @a, and @r work on bukkit. I'll just download Skript and do it like that.

Comment: That would do it. Good solution though